# Overture tool on Debian crashes everytime

Tags: debian, vdm++

I have installed Debian 7 on my computer. I installed Overture tool by downloading and extracting the .zip file. Every time I try to run Overture I get the following error message:

```
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f7ea122673f, pid=11073, tid=140182465734400
    #
    # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  [libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0+0x5173f]  gdk_display_open+0x3f
    #
    # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
    # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
    #
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should rather post a bug report to the project maintainers.

Comment: Melbius is quite right. Can you file a bug report here: https://github.com/overturetool/overture/issues

Comment: As this is a JRE error, can you try running with a Java 7 JRE? I assume you're using Overture 2.2.6? You're using the 64-bit build?

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing this right now.

Comment: Yes, I'm using 2.2.6 (64-bit). I will try running with Java 7 JRE. Thanks

Comment: I get the same error with Java 7 JRE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easy solution that you can find [here](http://github.com/overturetool/overture/issues/467#issuecomment-137376095)

Basically, SWT_GTK3 has to be set to 0 before running Overture. Hence, we can execute the following:

`$ export SWT_GTK3=0 && ./Overture`

Thanks for your help!